# No module named 'sqlserver_ado'

Tags: python, sql-server

I am using django and want to connect MSSQL. but while run the code i got the error that `No module named 'sqlserver_ado'`

Here are my settings

```
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
'NAME': 'wfmreport',
'Server' :  'XYZ',
'PORT' : '1533',
'USER' : 'sa',
'PASSWORD' :'xxxxx',
'USE_TZ': True,
```

}

Comment: Did you pip install the backend for sql server? ***pip install django-mssql***

Comment: Yes. i have installed the django-mssql . Now i am not bale to install the pywin 32

Comment: Can you update your question with the error?

Answer (score -1):

you need to install django-mssql by the command bellow

```
pip install django-mssql
```